# Android : How to make a Service That will periodically send the Users Location on a server

Tags: android, service, location

I am building the app that requires that users location has to be updated on my server periodically or to be more efficient only when its location has been updated.
For that a Service will run on its device.
But I am not able to develop that till now haven't found that does that perfectly.
Please help

Comment: Can you post what approach you have tried? Need more info to get an answer.

Comment: I am assuming he needs something that keeps updating a location on the server as the app is running .. I posted an answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Making a service that is continuously running in the background is a bad idea and would be a memory overload and also on the battery. Instead have it such that there is background updates being sent when the app in running on the foreground.

I would suggest you use an Intent service instead of a service , as that would spring a new thread and work in the background and also kills itself once the job is finished. It also has a queue system which gets executed one by one.

Use an intent service along with the LocationManager - [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).

The location manager has a location changed listener which needs to be implemented which looks for location updated events. If it is maps based, then GoogleMap object has a location change listener too.

-Tutorial for IntentService - [Link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/)

-Tutorial for Location Manager - [Link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html)

Hope this helps